# Using import package with foreach loop

Tags: import

I have nested folders with multiple files containing statements and solutions for exercices.

```
main.tex
exercices (folder)
⮑ statements (folder)
   ⮑  1.tex
   ⮑  2.tex
⮑ solutions (folder)
   ⮑  2.tex
```

From what I understand on few topics like [input files in different directories](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39083/input-files-in-different-directories?rq=1), you cannot input files from different nested directories and need to use the `import` package. So this was the previous code :

```
\foreach \filenumber in {1,2}{
  \IfFileExists{exercices/statements/\filenumber}{\input{exercices/statements/\filenumber}}
  \IfFileExists{exercices/solutions/\filenumber}{\input{exercices/solutions/\filenumber}}
}
```

The issue is that the following code still doesn't work with the `\import` command.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\foreach \filenumber in {1,2}{
  \IfFileExists{exercices/statements/\filenumber}{\import{exercices/statements/}{\filenumber}}
  \IfFileExists{exercices/solutions/\filenumber}{\import{exercices/solutions/}{\filenumber}}
  }
\end{document}
```

The code gives the error `LaTeX Error: File exercices/solutions/1.tex' not found.`

Comment: "From what I understand on few topics like input files in different directories, you cannot input files from different nested directories and need to use the import package." ?? you can always use `\input`, you may find `\import` helps with the syntax in some cases, although personally I think it makes things more complicated for little gain.

Comment: `\IfFileExists{exercices/statements/\filenumber}{\input{exercices/statements/\filenumber}}` can be simplified and made more efficient by `\InputIfFileExists{exercices/statements/\filenumber}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\foreach \filenumber in {1,2}{\InputIfFileExists{exercices/statements/\filenumber} \InputIfFileExists{exercices/solutions/\filenumber}}` inputs `1.tex` and `2.tex` from the `statements` folder but it doesn't input `2.tex` from the `solutions` folder.

I did not do anything in particular about the start, I'm using overleaf so I guess it starts from `main.tex` as usual.

Comment: Oh you are missing the yes and no arguments from the call see my `{}{No solution}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `\input` but here you simply want `\InputIfFileExists`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\foreach \filenumber in {1,2}{%
  \InputIfFileExists{exercices/statements/\filenumber}{}{}\par
  \InputIfFileExists{exercices/solutions/\filenumber}{}{No solution}\par
  }
\end{document}
```

The terminal and log show the three files being input:

```
(./exercices/statements/1.tex) (./exercices/solutions/1.tex)
(./exercices/statements/2.tex) [1
```

Producing

[image]

If you put suitable text such as "ex1" in `1.tex`